# How to install individual package (like commath) in LaTex?

Tags: packages, texlive, texmaker, installing, kile

I have trouble understanding how LaTex deals with packages, so this is a rather general question that arose from my specific problem with the commath package.

I want to use the commath package, and so I downloaded it from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/commath?lang=en). In order to install it I tried two different things:

**First Try**
I have used the amsmath package before, so I checked where on my system it's located and found this:

> /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath
> /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty

So I created a folder `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/commath` and placed the file `commath.sty` in it. I restarted my computer. It didn't work (with both kile and texmaker).

**Second Try**
As recommended in some forums, I checked my `TEXMFLOCAL` path:

> $kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
> /usr/local/share/texmf:/usr/share/texmf

Neither of these folders existed on my computer, so I created a folder `/usr/share/texmf`, created the folder `commath` in it, placed file `commath.sty` in the commath folder. I restarted my computer. Also didn't work.

So can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Why does kile/ texmaker use one package (amsmath) but not another, if they are in the same parent directory? How can I find out specifically which directories the editors search?

I use TexLive on Manjaro Linux.

Comment: If you are using miktex + somethinf, you need to add that folder to its path. Check next comment

Comment: https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console

Comment: there should be no need to install the package manually, it is in texlive. So install it with the texlive manager.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have texlive but no tlmgr. Also, as I said in my question, the question is not how to get the package installed but why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: @Jes I use texlive

Comment: your first try didn't work because you didn't call mktexlsr, but you shouldn't install manually in texmf-dist. The second is unclear, perhaps mktexlsr is missing too, or the tree is not known (it looks odd that there are two pathes in your TEXMFLOCAL variable), you could try TEXMFHOME instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, trying it in TEXMFHOME and executing mktexlsr worked, but now I have the same problem with apacite and it doesn't seem to do it. Sigh...

Comment: well apacite consist of 19 files, which must be first unpacked from the dtx and then go in various locations in the texmf tree.

Comment: About `commath` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=commath+user%3A4427 for reasons about not using it.

Comment: you really don't want to use commath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed TeX through a package manager, you want to install new packages for it through the same package manager.  You mention that this is Manjaro, so you would want to search the package list with `pacman -Ss` for keywords or `pacman -Qo` for files.  Or you might look for a package online.

Or, do a full installation of TeX Live, and you will probably never need to read past this sentence or worry about it ever again.

Generally, you’d look for a `.sty` file for packages you’d invoke with `\usepackage`. a `.cls` file for document classes, a `.tfm` file for legacy fonts, `.otf` or sometimes `.ttf` or `.ttc` for modern fonts, or `.mf` for really old fonts.

If you are using your own TeX Live installation, you will need to set the `PATH` to use its executables.  On Manjaro or Arch, its command-line utilities will not work by default.  You then want to search CTAN for the package you want, and see if it has a line like “Contained in  TeX Live as commath”.  You then install it with `tlmgr`.  You might need to run `tlmgr` through `sudo` or as an Administrator. Since I normally create an account just to install TeX, I have an `alias` in my shell for `sudo -u tex -E $(which tlmgr)`.

If you are running MikTeX, you would want to update via the MikTeX console.

Rarely, you might need to manually install a package that isn’t available through any package manager.  In this case, the best place to put it is usually the directory you found for `TEXMFLOCAL`, with the command

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

On Linux, you normally want to put your own files under `/usr/local/share/`, not `/usr/share/`.  Otherwise, you were on the right track: create your subdirectory and copy the files over.  If you’re installing your own packages like this, you almost certainly want to remove the outdated TeX that comes with your OS and install an up-to-date TeX Live or MikTeX.  Newer packages might not even work otherwise.

If you are running MikTeX rather than TeX Live, you will need to add this new directory as a local TeX tree in its console.

After copying over the files, run

```
texhash
updmap-sys
```

As whatever account owns your TeX installation.

If you are on a multi-user system and cannot save to `TEXMFLOCAL`, use `TEXMFHOME`.  You find its location similarly, with

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

As a last resort, you can create a directory such as `~/texmf` and try `TEXINPUTS=$HOME/texmf; export TEXINPUTS` to use it.

Comment: Great answer, just one minor comment: On Manjaro (and Arch), tlmgr does not work per default: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live#tlmgr